# Fixed line - listbox

Tags: tkinter, listbox

Is there any way to set a fixed line length of a listbox in tkinter? So that when a string of a larger size is inserted it will continue onto the next line?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to get an item in the listbox to wrap onto two or more lines.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to see a line wider than the widest possible listbox would be to use a horizontal scrollbar, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()
listo = Listbox(root, background='white', width=100)
listo.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
ybar = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient=VERTICAL, command=listo.yview)
ybar.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
xbar = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=listo.xview)
xbar.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=2, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
listo["yscrollcommand"] = ybar.set
listo["xscrollcommand"] = xbar.set
listo.insert('end', "When, in the course of human events, it becomes necessary for one people to dissolve the political bands which have connected them with another, and to assume, among the nations of the earth, that separate and equal station to which the laws of Nature and of Nature's God entitle them...")
root.mainloop()
```